# JSON formating when displaying in website

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm very(very) new to JSON and I can't understand how it works.
I have this function which displays the JSON in the website

```
function makeItem(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })
    return tbl_body;
}
```

I get that `k` and `v` are key and values but the function displays all the data from the JSON.

```
[{"ProductDataId":"132","ProductId":"20","FilterId":"40","ProductDataBG":"on","ProductDataEN":null},{"ProductDataId":"133","ProductId":"21","FilterId":"40","ProductDataBG":"on","ProductDataEN":null},{"ProductDataId":"134","ProductId":"22","FilterId":"40","ProductDataBG":"on","ProductDataEN":null}]
```

Let's say I want the dispalayed data(in the website) to be in different divs for the ProductDataId, ProductId etc(not in table as it is now).
The question is how to make that happen? I think that I should change something in `tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";` but I'm not sure if that will be the only change and how to get specific info(something like `v['ProductDataId']`?).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: using a templater like mustache.js will make your already difficult life easier

Comment: You basically need to predetermine the html structure you want the data to be displayed in. Then as you loop over the data you create the necessary elements that make up the wanted structure. Start with raw html page as your *"template"*...then reverse engineer it

Comment: @charlietfl I have the template but didn't know how to separated the different elements. I get it now. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @dandavis I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wouldn't do the 2nd `$.each`. Just access the object properties directly like so:

```
function makeItem(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";

        tbl_row += "<td>"+this.ProductDataId+"</td>";
        tbl_row += "<td>"+this.ProductId+"</td>";

        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })
    return tbl_body;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it now.